# AWS service to use for a .net core 2.1 Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, .net-core, hosting

I'm new to AWS and but would like to use their services. I've been doing some research but I get very confused about the following:

I have a .net core 2.1 web api that I would like to host on AWS. I know this is possible but I'm not sure which service to use. I was looking at EC2 but I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right service. So my two questions are:

What AWS service should I use to host a web api (written in .net core 2.1)? 
And are there multiple possibilities for such a service on AWS?

Side note: I would also like to use RDS to host my database (But I got that pretty much figured out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have many options:

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-2-1-and-aws/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-ecs-aspnetcore-ec2.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. This is indeed what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy Cloud Computing :)